# Unable to create ssh tunnel through php_exec

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

I'm trying to create a temporary tunnel via php so I can query a remote database.
The following code works through php-cli and as a shell command, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it trough apache:

```
$connect = "ssh -i remotekey -f -L 3315:localhost:3306 user@<remote IP> sleep 20 >> /tmp/logfile";
$out = shell_exec($connect);
```

A few notes:

- remotekey is owned by wwwrun (the apache user under openSuse), perms are at 600
- The logfile in /tmp gets created (and is blank)
- safe_mode is off
- Using PHP 5.3.17

After opening the site, I check the running processes for the background ssh and get nothing.

If I run it through php-cli, I see the tunnel running.

This has been driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The issue was with the command silently failing as the apache user due to the remote server not being in the known_hosts file for the apache user.
Running the command with:

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

circumvented this and the tunnel now works.

Thanks to the helpful folks who pointed me in the right direction in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried running the CLI version as the Apache user?

Comment: Note that your web server probably runs as a different user. Have you tried running `ssh` interactively as that user? You will probably find that either it cannot access the key or that the remote host is not in the `known_hosts` file.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

It was indeed a known_hosts issue and I confirmed it by running the command via the php-cli as apache (wwwrun).

Adding -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ignores that and appears to work well.